# paint polygon collider during gameplay

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

I'm working on a 2D game in which some objects have a triangular vision, done with a polygon collider[image]

Is it possible to paint this collider so that it is visible during the gameplay?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your mean `PolygonCollider2D` and that it always has 3 points in the correct order I guess you could do something like

```c#
using System.Linq;

...

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(PolygonCollider2D))]
public class MeshCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake ()
    {
        var points = GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().points;
        var meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        var mesh = new Mesh();

        // Just a shorthand for something like 
        //var list = new List<Vector3>();
        //foreach(var p in points)
        //{
        //    list.Add(p);
        //}
        //mesh.vertices = list.ToArray();
        mesh.vertices = points.Select(p -> (Vector3) p).ToArray();

        // Here create two triangles (each 3 vertices)
        // just because I don't know if you have the points in the correct order
        mesh.triangles = new int[]{0,1,2,0,2,1};

        meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
    }
}
```

and put this component next to the `PolygonCollider2D`. It will then replace this Object's mesh with the triangle.

The material you can already set beforehand in the `MeshRenderer`.

For getting this overlap area the simplest solution would be Semi-Transparent materials. Otherwise you might need a special shader.

Comment: The line `mesh.triangles = new int[0,1,2,0,2,1]` won't compile, the `triangle` attribute seems to be expecting for a `int[]` instead of `int[,,,,,]`.

Comment: @Daniel type it on my phone and didn't take care there ;) fixed it